# How can I add an AnimationEvent receiver/listener outside the GameObject that has the Animator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, event-handling

I have a GameObject with an Animator and some animations that can trigger an event (with a specific callback function).

[image]

As long as I add a Script to the same GameObject as the Animator, that includes the receiver, everything works fine:

[image]

```
public class AnimatorEventReceiver : MonoBehaviour {
    
    void OnAnimationEnd( AnimationEvent animationEvent ) {
        // do something
    }
    
}
```

*(it's a simplified example, I stripped anything unecessary)*

My problem is: I have to listen for this event outside of the GameObject that contains the Animator. I have full access to the GameObject itself, how can I externally add an "EventListener" to listen for this AnimationEvent?

I'm kind of looking for the Unity/C# equivalent of a Javascript "object.addEventListener( callback )"

The object that should receive the AnimationEvent, is the parent of the GameObject containing the Animator - if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly but you could forward it via a normal event like e.g.

```
public class AnimatorEventReceiver : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public event Action<AnimationEvent> OnAnimationEnded;

    void OnAnimationEnd(AnimationEvent animationEvent) 
    {
        AnimationEnded?.Invoke(animationEvent);
    }      
}
```

Then any other object that "knows" you object can do e.g.

```
public AnimatorEventReceiver eventReceiver;

private void Awake ()
{
    eventReceiver.OnAnimationEnded += HandleAnimationEnded;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    eventReceiver.OnAnimationEnded += HandleAnimationEnded;
}

private void HandleAnimationEnded(AnimationEvent animationEvent)
{
    // Do something
}
```

---

Or alternatively you could also use Unity's built-in `UnityEvent` so you can setup callbacks already in the Inspector (similar to e.g. Button onClick)

```
// I know .. please come up with a better name :D
[Serializable]
public class AnimationEventEvent : UnityEvent<AnimationEvent> { }

public class AnimatorEventReceiver : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public AnimationEventEvent OnAnimationEnded;

    void OnAnimationEnd(AnimationEvent animationEvent) 
    {
        AnimationEnded.Invoke(animationEvent);
    }      
}
```

Then you can either add callbacks in the Inspector or any other object that "knows" you object can do e.g.

```
public AnimatorEventReceiver eventReceiver;

private void Awake ()
{
    eventReceiver.OnAnimationEnded.AddListener( HandleAnimationEnded);
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    eventReceiver.OnAnimationEnded.RemoveListener( HandleAnimationEnded);
}

private void HandleAnimationEnded(AnimationEvent animationEvent)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this too - but I figured there had to be a better way with access to the Animator. Well, I'll give it a bit of time - if nobody else has a better way, I'll take yours :)